# Floyd Rose screws are too tight?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, maintenance

My Floyd Rose screw is too tight. I am using a Kramer 7 string guitar with Floyd Rose, and I was attempting to install D-tuna.

I have successfully installed the D-tuna on my 7th string before (i.e., I have no problems with the screw), but this time, I cannot put back my 6th string after changing strings. The string-locking screw is so tight that I cannot screw in more than 1cm, and paint on the screw is being stripped.

Is there any possible reason for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the screw misthreaded. If the screw thread alignment isn't correct when you start the screw, it will go in for a little way before hanging up. Unfortunately, working a screw in while misthreaded usually damages the starting threads and makes it more difficult to start the screw correctly.

You should remove the screw and replace it in the screw hole by hand, working it back and forth while you push in on it, slightly turning it until you feel it catch, then screw in by hand. You should do this without the string in first. If you can get the screw to move freely and screw in normally, then you can replace the string.

If the screw hole threads are too damaged to find the correct alignment, then the damaged threads need to be fixed. Sometimes brushing them with a wire brush will clear the threads enough. Other methods are to use a thread tap to re cut the starting threads, or a thread chasing tool.